# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError при использовании изображений

Tags: android

Вылетает приложение с ошибкой java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tren.SportPit.BSprogramm/tren.SportPit.BSprogramm.LayTrapeciaOne}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #187: Error inflating      class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
at tren.SportPit.BSprogramm.LayTrapeciaOne.onCreate(LayTrapeciaOne.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Слишком большое изображение в ImageView лайаута. Каков вопрос - таков ответ.

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как задать вопрос, мне выдало такую ошибку, и я тоже заметил, что что-то с ИмагаВью, но что именно, я так и не понял, просто решил выложить сюда лог, думал, тут мне помогут, если бы мне при ошибке еще больше информации выдали, я бы и ее предоставил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что ж, ошибка действительно связана с невозможностью загрузки (+ декодирования) изображения из ресурсов в ImageView. Причем ошибка далеко необязательно связана со слишком большим размером графического файла (достаточно заглянуть внутрь BitmapFactory, чтобы понять это).

Исходя из размытой проблемы, привожу ниже связанную информацию, анализировать которую остается вам:

1. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820266/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-out-of-memory-with-a-400kb-file-with-2mb-f