# OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, java

Не понимаю, в чем проблема.

```
    01-01 16:05:59.597  12166-12166/com.example.PoemsAndFace E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 28311568-byte allocation.
01-01 16:05:59.621  12166-12166/com.example.PoemsAndFace E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:521)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:374)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:397)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:427)
            at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:446)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
            at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:165)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:885)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1990)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2895)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2938)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:279)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.PoemsAndFace.Authors.onCreate(Authors.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все же видно, как на ладони в стактрейсе:Где-то в XML файле layout'а выставлена картинка слишком большого размера. Возможно, кстати, она только часть проблемы. Может быть основная часть памяти съедается где-то в другом месте, до этого момента.
Большие изображения лучше класть в папку `drawable-nodpi`

P. S. что бы выделить код так, как это сделал модератор, выдели мышкой весь код, и нажми на `{}` в панели инструментов
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Был уже подобный вопрос с идентичной проблемой( логами из LogCat ): [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError при использовании изображений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/363033/android-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Проблема в том, я удаляю Маин активити при переходе во 2 активтити, после я удаляю 2 активити и перехожу в 3 активити, а при переходе из 3 активти во 2 активити возникает эта ошибка. в дебаг режиме нормально все работает, если без дебага запустить, то будет эта ошибка. Если убрать finish() В MainActivity то этой ошибки не будет.

Comment: @xTIGRx значит картинка, что во 2 активити забивает память только со второго раза. скажите разрешение картинки, что вставляете, и еще на каком дивайсе крашится?

Comment: Лежит в drawable картинка 1536 2048 размер 383 кб. В классе прописано что по нажатии на кнопку с картинокй удаляеться активти и переход.

Comment: а что говорит по этому поводу DDMS ?

Comment: @xTIGRx, время расчётов!

1536х2048х8 (высотаХширинаХглубина) = 25165824 байт

25165824 / 1048576 (переводим в мегабайты для наглядности) = 24 Мб.

В итоге получается, что исходное изображение развёртывается в памяти так, что вместо 383 кб (наверно вы ещё картинку в jpg храните) выходит 24 Мб, поэтому у вас и выходит ошибка OutOfMemory (исчерпан лимит ОЗУ, выделенный приложению). Мой вам совет - хотя бы в несколько раз уменьшите изображение, вряд ли оно реально понадобится в таком большом разрешении.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, о чем частично и было сказано по приведенной выше ссылке..